# listener never be invoked with spring cloud bus and kafka

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-cloud

For refreshing configuration dynamically(without restart) on client with Spring Cloud Bus and kafka([spring cloud bus](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-bus/2.0.0.RC1/single/spring-cloud-bus.html)). In kafka, it seems pub/sub works normally from console. But the listener of client never be invoked.

output of kafka command: bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server host:9092 --topic springCloudBus --from-beginning

```
 contentType
"text/plain"originalContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"{"type":"MyCustomRemoteEvent","timestamp":1524625355729,"originService":"application:db:8090","destinationService":"client:**","id":"9cb283d1-dc2f-4e63-80aa-03c9f52f773f","message":"<debug info>"}

 contentType
"text/plain"originalContentType "application/json;charset=UTF-8"{"type":"AckRemoteApplicationEvent","timestamp":1524625355786,"originService":"client:8888","destinationService":"**","id":"dc4e42ee-ffba-427c-9c12-b493b262b29c","ackId":"9cb283d1-dc2f-4e63-80aa-03c9f52f773f","ackDestinationService":"client:**","event":"com.ifly.icourt.event.listener.MyCustomRemoteEvent"}
```

server project, publish message

```
String myUniqueId = context.getId(); 
// send message to service named "client"
MyCustomRemoteEvent event = new MyCustomRemoteEvent(this, myUniqueId, "client", "<debug info>"); 
context.publishEvent(event);
```

client project, subscribe message, application.properties

```
# specify application context id
spring.application.name=client
```

event

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyCustomRemoteEvent extends RemoteApplicationEvent {

    private String message;  

    public MyCustomRemoteEvent() {  
    }  

    public MyCustomRemoteEvent(Object source, String originService, String destinationService, String message) {  
        super(source, originService, destinationService);  
        this.message = message;  
    }  

    public String getMessage() {  
        return message;  
    }  

    public void setMessage(String message) {  
        this.message = message;  
    }  
}
```

Why is the listener never invoked?

```
@Component
public class NewListener implements ApplicationListener<MyCustomRemoteEvent> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NewListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(MyCustomRemoteEvent event) {
        System.out.println("<debug info> listener is invoked");
        String message = event.getMessage();
        logger.info("<debug info> get message: " + message);
    }   
}
```

**Add**
After adding eureka, listener works well and can be invoked. Is eureka necessary to make Spring Cloud Bus and kafka work?

Comment: what version of spring boot and spring cloud are you using?

Comment: @spencergibb spring boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, spring cloud Dalston.SR4.